# LocalDate formatter bug?

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, localdate

I found strange behaviour when using Java's DateTimeFormatter on LocalDate for 30th and 31st of December.

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.DECEMBER, 30);
System.out.println("date1:           " + date1);
System.out.println("converted date1: " + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date1));

LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 30);
System.out.println("date2:           " + date2);
System.out.println("converted date2: " + DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date2));
```

Output:

```
date1:           2019-12-30
converted date1: 2020-12-30
date2:           2019-01-30
converted date2: 2019-01-30
```

The first date (December 30) is converted with the next year, the second date (January 30) is converted with the correct year.

Am I missing something out, or is it a bug?

Comment: You probably wanted `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. You need to be careful with those patterns, they're not just random letters.

Comment: A handy tip to keep in mind: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Y` means "year of week-based year". It's not the same as `y` which means "year of era" as per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

[This post](https://coderanch.com/t/619912/certification/Difference-Year-Week-year-SimpleDateFormat) explains the difference and purpose of `Y`:

> A week year is a year where all the weeks in the year are whole weeks. This is specified by some standard (which I don't remember at the moment). Basically, this guarantees that a program working on a week's data will not transition between years. Unfortunately, this also means that the beginning of the year may not start on the first of January. What year a particular day belongs in depends on these rules, and of course, there are days where the year and the week year are different.

In your example 30st Dec '19 was a Monday, 31st Dec '19 was a Tuesday and 1st Jan '20 was Wednesday so "year of week-based year" for this three days is 2020.

Comment: I would say "`Y` means 'year of week-based year' and `y` means 'year of era'" just to be super clear.

Comment: Lesson learned - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Change 'Y' to 'y' (Capital case to lower case) 'Y' is week based year and since most of the week of Dec-30, 2019 falls into 2020 the year is 2020. while lower case 'y' is your regular year. See JavaDoc for [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details

Comment: Thanks as well Michael :)